# Getting cookie=None always in pythonforfacebook appengine example

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, python-2.5

I am trying to execute the appengineexample of https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/. However, my cookie value is always None. I did debug and find that it does carry information however in facebook.get_user_from_cookie, it cannot extract/parse the value.

Has anyone been able to execute this example? I am using Python25. I am trying to implement a similar funcitonality in my example.

I need to log in users via facebook and store their details in app engine datastore.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons produce this issue. 
We could not help if there is no details information.
Try to log some information will help us to firgure out what the bug is.

https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/facebook.py

Since you received None with get_user_from_cookie function.
open the facebook.py, add two log at the line that will produce the None results. Then the log can tell where the issue is.

```
def get_user_from_cookie(cookies, app_id, app_secret):
    """Parses the cookie set by the official Facebook JavaScript SDK.

    cookies should be a dictionary-like object mapping cookie names to
    cookie values.

    If the user is logged in via Facebook, we return a dictionary with
    the keys "uid" and "access_token". The former is the user's
    Facebook ID, and the latter can be used to make authenticated
    requests to the Graph API. If the user is not logged in, we
    return None.

    Download the official Facebook JavaScript SDK at
    http://github.com/facebook/connect-js/. Read more about Facebook
    authentication at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/.
    """
    cookie = cookies.get("fbsr_" + app_id, "")
    if not cookie:
        logging.info("no cookies")   # ADD LOG HERE!
        return None
    parsed_request = parse_signed_request(cookie, app_secret)
    try:
        result = get_access_token_from_code(parsed_request["code"], "",
                                          app_id, app_secret)
    except GraphAPIError:
        logging.info("get access token failed") # ADD LOG HERE!!
        return None
    result["uid"] = parsed_request["user_id"]
    return result
```

Comment: So I did as you said and I am getting "no cookies" I debugged and noticed that the control goes to "def cookies" in webob (Google\google_appengine\lib\webob_0_9\webob) and here self.str_cookies is empty and hence vars is {}. So when the control returns to get_user_from_cookie, cookie is None :( I am wondering if I need to use gaesessions (https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/). I have had ot use this before in a project where we needed session management.

Comment: Did you use Facebook javascript SDK together? The facebook javascript SDK will implement the cookie part for you. or you are trying to implement Server-Side Authentication without javascript SDK? then you need to do the cookie part by your self.

Comment: No, I have very much used javascript SDK on client side with cookie=true in FB.init. I am not sure what am I missing. I have used the entire example as is from sdk -> examples->appengine